# How to get a down vector just from a normal vector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

I have got a 3D game running. The red rectangle is my player on some kind of ramp or house roof. He is not rotated. Now when he falls on such a ramp I can get the green vector by the RaycastHit normal.
But what I want to get is the purple vector, so I can give my player the velocity to slide down. How do I get that vector or is it impossible with the variables given?

The purple vector is the closest vector to `Vector3.down` that is tangent to the roof.

[image]

Edit: I guess I figured out how to get to that Vector but I still don't understand how to calculate it. In the second picture vector a and b is given. Now I need to get vector c, which is 90 degrees from a to b.

[image]

Figured it out. If anyone is wondering: I just used the Vector3.RotateTowards like this:

```
rigid.velocity = Vector3.RotateTowards(hit.normal, -transform.up, Mathf.PI / 2, 0);
```

Comment: What you need is to calculate the slope (as in the mathematics concept) of the face you're landing on. Google "unity slope" and you should find some results.

Comment: Well that did not help that much with my problem, but I figured it out myself now.

Comment: @made3 If you figured it out, you should post an answer instead of modifying the question.

Comment: I'm still not even getting which vectors you want ... pretty hard to understand with your 2-dimensional drawings ^^

Comment: @made3 Answers do not belong in the body of the question. They should be added below as an answer so that users can vote on how helpful each answer is. Consider adding what you did to solve your question below and editing out the answer from the body of the question. You can--and should--accept your own answer if you find that it's the most helpful! [See here for more information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74101/what-to-do-when-op-answers-his-her-own-question-in-an-edit).

Answer (score 2):

The vector you are looking for is the vector orthogonal to the normal of the surface that is closest to the direction of gravity (typically `Vector3.down`).  You can use vector cross product to find this:

```
Vector3 surfaceNormal;
Vector3 directionOfGravity = Vector3.down;
Vector3 slopeSideways = Vector3.Cross(directionOfGravity, surfaceNormal);
if (slopeSideways != Vector3.zero)
{
    Vector3 slopeDown = Vector3.Cross(surfaceNormal, slopeSideways).normalized;
}
else
{
    // surface is normal to the direction of gravity, there is no downwards slope.
}
```